# Correct usage of Response.Write() in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to force a download of an XML file when the user visits a page.

This is the code I am using

```
public partial class GenerateTemplate : LayoutsPageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //.............
        //Going about generating my XML
        //.............
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=template.xml");
        Response.Write(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

I am facing a problem that my download window hangs indefinitely, without ever completing the download/Open of the file.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not disposing any objects or closing any connections here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've posted [a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570433/create-text-file-and-download/4570593#4570593) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570433/create-text-file-and-download). To quote myself:

Just a small addition to the other answers. At the very end of a download I execute:

```
context.Response.Flush();
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I learned that otherwise, the download sometimes does not complete successfully.

[This Google Groups posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570433/create-text-file-and-download/4570593#4570593) also notes that `Response.End` throws a `ThreadAbortException` which you could avoid by using the `CompleteRequest` method.

Comment: Is it a good habit to reply in such a manner or should I post this as a comment only to the initial question?

Comment: CompleteRequest and Response.End are completely different.  CompleteRequest does -not- stop the rest of the ASP.NET pipeline from processing; it only affects the HTTP pipeline. You're in the ASP.NET part of the HTTP pipeline, and the asp.net handler will continue processing unless you call Response.End.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Response.End()` instead of `Flush` and `Close`

That's what I have been using in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the content type and calling `Response.End()`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.............
    //Going about generating my XML
    //.............
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";        
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.xml");
    Response.Write(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You say you want to have a file **download** With asp.net web forms you would do this:

```
context.Response.ContentType = //MIME type

// Set the filename 
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + queryFile); 

// Stream the file to the client 
context.Response.WriteFile(file);
```

Comment: I do not have a file in a physical server. The XML file exists as an XMLDocument object in the memory. For this reason, I cannot use WriteFile() method.

Comment: ok! Sorry, I thought the `WriteFile` method would have an overload that takes a stream (Much like mvc's controller.File does) Maybe you can try Writing to the output stream. See :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx