# How to return export path without using copy to memory2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-7.0

I working on web API asp.net core 3.1 I need to return export path direct without copying to memory

so How to do that Please ?

How to return export path without copy to memory as below

```
return File(memory2, "text/plain", Path.GetFileName(exportPath));
```

meaning using export Path instead of using memory2

with another meaning i need after get result on file export path

return it directly without copy to memory

What I have tried:

```
public IActionResult Upload()
    {
foreach (var m in mods)
                      {
                          List<InputExcel> inputmodulelist = new List<InputExcel>();
                          inputmodulelist = inputexcellist.Where(x => x.ModuleName == m).ToList();
                          var dtimport = DatatableConversion.ToDataTable(inputmodulelist);
                          DataTable dtexport = new DataTable();
                          dtexport = _deliveryService.LoadExcelToDataTable(_connectionString, dtimport);
                          ex.Export(dtexport, m, exportPath);
            
                      }
                  }
                  var memory2 = new MemoryStream();
                  using (var stream = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Open))
                  {
                      stream.CopyTo(memory2);
                  }
                  memory2.Position = 0;
            
                  return File(memory2, "text/plain", Path.GetFileName(exportPath));
```

Comment: A "return File()" response returns *THREE* things from the server to your browser: 1) the file contents (the bytes in your file), 2) the file's MIME type (e.g. "text/plain"), 3) the filepath (e.g. so your browser can write the file's contents to disk).  Q: Which of those three things don't you like, and want to change?  Exactly what's wrong with the way it works now  Please clarify.

Comment: i need to return file to download it on client

Comment: can you show me how by modifiying code above

Comment: 1) the file contents (the bytes in your file) this option what i need to make it

Comment: Have you tried any of the other overloads? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: So why do you need "MemoryStream" at all? Just return a ContentResult(): [Create text file and download without saving on server in ASP.net Core MVC 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501257/421195)

Comment: Why are you copying the file into memory? Why don't you just provide the `FileStream` to the `File` method?

Comment: how to return content result

Comment: can you show me please by code modify if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you want to download file without reading the file content into the memory, right?

If that is the case, you could directly read the file via the `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()` method, code as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;
    public ToDoController(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
        environment = hostEnvironment;
    } 
    [HttpGet("download")]
    public IActionResult Download()
    {
        var exportPath = Path.Combine( environment.WebRootPath, "files","Image1.jpg");
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(exportPath), "image/png", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(exportPath));
    }
```

When calling the above action method, it will download the image file. You can change the [file's MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) to download different file.